# Having issues when subdividing human model

Tags: modifiers, uv, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm using a subdivision modifier to fix 2 meshes with low geometry and each has its own issue. First is the mouth mesh. This model uses multiple different mouth models as expressions although it does have a semi-working face rig. When I put subdivision on it, the corners of it get messed up and it doesn't look connected to the face anymore:

Mouth without a *Subdivision Surface modifier*:
[image: mouth w/o subdiv]

Mouth with the *Subdivision Surface modifier* enabled:
[image: mouth with subdiv]

The second issue is when I subdivide the body mesh. When I do this, the top that the character is wearing gets distorted. The neck also doesn't seem to be connected to the body anymore because of the subdivision.

Body, *Subdivision Surface modifier* disabled:
[image: body no subdiv]

Body, *Subdivision Surface modifier* enabled:
[image: body with subdiv]

This is all in an attempt to smooth the meshes so they are more pleasant to look at.

[Link to the pictures in a Google drive folder along with the blend file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VDq0tQn8oTqutyqUrmPGBa03TtSEVxJ-?usp=sharing)

Comment: You objects are probably using Ngons

Comment: how can i fix that? also what is an ngon?

Comment: 1) The mouth is a separate, loose mesh. The *Subdisivion Surface* modifier makes the sharp corners round and this creates the holes that you can see. You either need to merge the vertices (Merge By Distance, key M) or use a *Weld* non-destructive modifier. But I am not sure how this affects the UV map and the weights for the rig. 2) The mesh is triangulated. The *Subdisivion Surface* does not work very well with such a mesh. The texture is aligned with the faces, and as the subdiv modifier moves the vertices around the shirt, it becomes distorted.

Comment: You can dissolve edges and use the knife tool to create a cleaner quad topology that works better with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Unfortunately, Blender's *Tris to Quads* command messes up the UV map and the texture. I'm not sure, why this happens. I will have a look later. -- An Ngon is a face with more than 4 vertices.